# How to retain original npm module functional ability while mocking it for jest testing?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, momentjs

I am trying to mock the "moment" library so I can run snapshot tests without worrying about "current" timestamps generated automatically via `moment()` to distort my snapshots.

However, I can't seem to create a mocked version of `moment()` without losing the regular functionality of the library.

Here is what i tried:

```
src/tests/__mocks__/moment.ts
-----------------------------

const moment = require.requireActual("moment");

export default (timestamp: any = 0) => {
  return moment(timestamp);
};
```

The logic behind this mock is that it should simple over-ride calles to `moment()` which do not have a timestamp of any sort and instead of letting it generate a current moment it will generate an `moment(0)` moment. All the other functionality should be retained, e.g: `moment("2010-05-10")` should generate a valid moment for `May 10th 2010` and other chained functions like `moment().startOf("month")` should also still work.

However, whenever jest encounters any sort of `moment()` declaration in my code it gives the following error in the terminal testing output:

`TypeError: moment is not a function`

How can solve this?